# Shelf life of homemade kombucha vinegar

Tags: food-safety, vinegar, kombucha

How long does homemade kombucha vinegar last on the shelf (non refrigerated)? Or are there signs to tell it’s gone bad beyond the it smells bad?

Comment: Vinegar is created through fermentation, if it's been made correctly vinegar has an indefinite shelf life as it is too acidic for bacteria to grow in it. If it is going bad then it's not really vinegar.

Answer (score 0):

Any type of vinegar is essentially immortal (in a closed container) for shelf life purposes.